# Proving $I(E(\Bbb C))=\left< y^2-x^3-ax-b\right>$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, ideals, elliptic-curves

Let $E/\Bbb C : y^2=x^3+ax+b$ be an elliptic curve over $\Bbb C$. Let
$$E(\Bbb C)=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb C^2:y^2=x^3+ax+b\}$$
be the affine variety generated by $E$. Finally, let
$$I(E(\Bbb C))=\{f(x,y)\in\Bbb C[x,y]: f(p)=0,\, \forall p\in E(\Bbb C)\}.$$
I am trying to show that $I(E(\Bbb C))=I_E$ is the ideal generated by $E$, that is,
$$I_E=\left< y^2-x^3-ax-b\right>\subset\Bbb C[x,y].$$

My attempt so far has been the following.

Suppose $f\in\Bbb C[x,y]$. Then we can divide by $y^2-x^3-ax-b$ and get
$$f(x,y)=q(x,y)(y^2-x^3-ax-b)+r(x,y),$$
where the total degree of $r\in\Bbb C[x,y]$ is less than $3$. Suppose then, that $f$ vanishes on $E(\Bbb C)$. That is, $f\in I_E$. From the uniformalization theorem, there is a lattice $L\subset \Bbb C$ such that $a=-15G_4(L),$ and $b=-35G_6(L)$, where $G_4,G_6$ are Eisenstein series corresponding to $L$. Because of this, the point $(\wp(z,L),\tfrac12\wp'(z,L))$ is in $E(\Bbb C)$ for all $z\in\Bbb C$. Here, $\wp(z,L)$ is the Weierstrass Elliptic function corresponding to the lattice $L$. Thus,
$$0=f(\wp,\tfrac12\wp')=q(\wp,\tfrac12\wp')(\tfrac14\wp'^2-\wp^3-a\wp-b)+r(\wp,\tfrac12\wp').$$
Due to the differential equation
$$\frac14\wp'(z,L)^2=\wp(z,L)^3-15G_4(L)\wp(z,L)-35G_6(L),$$
we then have that
$$r(\wp,\tfrac12\wp')=0.$$
All I need to show now is that $r(x,y)$ is identically equal to $0$, but I am not quite sure how. One thing I considered is to write
$$r(x,y)=\beta_1x^2+\beta_2xy+\beta_3y^2+\beta_3x+\beta_5y+\beta_6,$$
so that
$$\begin{align}
r(\wp,\tfrac12\wp')&=\beta_1\wp^2+\tfrac12\beta_2\wp\wp'+\tfrac14\beta_3\wp'^2+\beta_4\wp+\tfrac12\beta_5\wp'+\beta_6\\
&=\beta_1\wp^2+\tfrac12\beta_2\wp\wp'+\beta_3(\wp^3+a\wp+b)+\beta_4\wp+\tfrac12\beta_5\wp'+\beta_6\\
&=\beta_3\wp^3+\beta_1\wp^2+(a\beta_3+\beta_4)\wp+\tfrac12(\beta_2\wp+\beta_5)\wp'+\beta_6+b\beta_3\\
&= 0.
\end{align}$$
Then using the expansion
$$\wp(z,L)=\frac1{z^2}+\sum_{n\ge1}(2n+1)G_{2n+2}(L)z^{2n},$$
the expansion of $\beta_3\wp^3+\beta_1\wp^2+(a\beta_3+\beta_4)\wp$ would only contain even powers of $z$, while the expansion of $\tfrac12(\beta_2\wp+\beta_5)\wp'$ would only contain odd powers of $z$, making the coefficient of $z^n$ of $r(\wp,\tfrac12\wp')$ be $0$ for all $n\ne0$, and the constant term of $r(\wp,\tfrac12\wp')$ equal to $-\beta_6-b\beta_3$.

I was hoping that this would then imply that $r(x,y)\equiv 0$, but I am not exactly sure if that works.

Is there a way to show that $r\equiv 0$ from here? Or perhaps an easier way to show that $f\in\left<y^2-x^3-ax-b\right>$? Thanks.

---

Edit for context:

I encountered this problem by looking through my old notes from my undergrad algebraic geometry class. I was wondering how I could apply what I learned from the class to elliptic curves.

Comment: Division with rest is a good idea, let us do this in the ring $\Bbb C[X][Y]$, i.e. we have a $Y$-degree one or less rest of the shape $a(X)Y +b(X)$. If $a\not\equiv 0$, extract $Y$...

Comment: would the down-voter care to explain?

Comment: Not me, i consider the question a good question, a lot of work has been invested to go into details and show/type them... the downvoter may reconsider...

Comment: Sure, you've given no details about how you're encountering this problem and what your familiarity with the concepts involved is. (For instance, how much algebraic geometry have you seen? Going immediately to the Weierstrass functions is a wiiiiild way to try answering this which is only done by people who know a ton or no algebraic geometry.) I think trying to answer this question is pretty difficult since the quick solutions I know may prompt ~10 comments of back and forth if I use a bunch of facts you don't know. Succinctly: please explain your background and how you came to consider this.

Comment: If $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ then $y^2-x^3-ax-b=0$. Now consider the kernel of the quotient map and what that means with regard to $f(p)$.

Comment: @HankScorpio I have taken an undergrad course in algebraic geometry, so I don't know that much. I do, however, have a lot of experience with special functions and analytic number theory. I thought to use the Weierstrass function, because I know it parameterizes the elliptic curve via its differential equation. I was not aware of a simpler parameterization that could be used.

Comment: Thank you for adding some information! Now, how did you encounter this problem? (Please consider adding the information to the *post* with an edit - it will be more visible to other readers and it will let people change their votes.) Also, there really isn't much in the way of better parametrizations, but that's not the point - this isn't a problem you solve with parametrization.

Comment: @HankScorpio please see the edit

Comment: Thank you for adding that! See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $p$ is a polynomial vanishing on $E$. Then after dividing $p$ by $y^2-(x^3+ax+b)$, we have $p=(y^2-(x^3+ax+b))q+r$, where $r$ has degree at most one in $y$. So we can write $r(x,y)=c(x)y+d(x)$, and $p$ vanishes on $E$ iff $r$ does (clearly $y^2-(x^3+ax+b)$ vanishes on $E$).

Now let $\overline{r}=-c(x)y+d(x)$. Then $r\overline{r}$ vanishes on $E$, and therefore $$r\overline{r} = c(x)^2-d(x)^2y^2 = c(x)^2 - d(x)^2(x^3+ax+b)$$ is a polynomial in $x$ which vanishes for all $x\in\Bbb C$. But this implies it is the zero polynomial, and for reasons of degree, this gives that $c=d=0$. So $r=0$ and in fact $p$ is divisible by $y^2-(x^3+ax+b)$.

One can get an awful lot of mileage out of this conjugation technique for varieties with equations of the form $z^2+pz+q=0$, just like one can get a lot of mileage out of conjugation for the complex numbers.

Comment: This is extremely clever, thank you so much!